# How do I get rid of the UAC everytime I start my application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation, registry, uac

I have signed my application with Verisign, stored all registry variables in HKCU in order not to request for admin right but the UAC command still prompts the user whether he/she wants the  following to make changes to his/her computer. How do I prevent this from happening.

**Below shows the manifest file generated by VS**

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32'              name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls'        version='6.0.0.0'                               processorArchitecture='x86'                   publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df'               language='*' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Can you show us the content of your application manifest?

Comment: I have added the manifest file generated in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation of this behaviour is found, as I suspected, in the application manifest. You have specified a requested execution level of `requireAdministrator`. It is that setting that results in the UAC dialog being shown. Change that to `asInvoker` to avoid requesting elevation.

```
....
<requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
....
```

There may well be a setting in the Visual Studio IDE to control this. I'm not familiar with that, but I expect that's the way you'll need to bring about this change. OK, I looked this up. The IDE setting is in the Linker node of the configuration pages, under the Manifest File section. Documentation of that can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx

Read about [application manifests over on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation!!! Really appreciate it. Will do the changes right away and let you know the outcome. Cheers.

Comment: Hey I have changed the manifest file according to the instructions but still getting prompted for UAC!! I don't know what is causing this. Also, I can confirm that the .exe created by Visual Studio in release does not contain admin rights but after generating the install file with inno setup i.e. writing registry values to HKCU and copying a few files, the application icon seen after install will seem to contain admin rights.

Comment: Can we keep your installation program out of this. Let's concentrate on the executable generated by the compiler. In that last comment you described a whole bunch of steps that are not mentioned in the question. Remember that we are here to answer the question that you asked, and not to solve the problem behind that question.

Comment: Okay, I think the executable generated by the compiler is Ok in terms of the privileges required after changing the manifest according to your previous answer. Now I have just tried installing the package on a different directory e.g. C:\ and it starts up without the UAC but with error reading my application database which I am yet to investigate so I think installing in C:\program files has something to do with the UAC prompt.

Comment: So, did I answer the question that you asked?

Comment: Well partially, Yes! since I can't yet get rid of the UAC with the preferred install directory i.e. C:\program files

Comment: You are getting mixed up with solving your problem, and the answering of the question that you asked. I answered the question that you asked. If you want to ask a question about your installer, then make that a different question.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, kind of new here so I have just edited the question to reflect my current condition.

Comment: You should ask a new question.